# SQL Linked Server Connection to Excel 2003 .xls file failed - SQL Server Management Studio V18

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, connection-string, linked-server

Question:
I am trying to create a linked server to excel 2003 but it keeps failing. I have already installed Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. I tried two different ways (Code 1 and Code 2), both of which are failing. I tried many options from the internet all of which are failing. Please your kind support.

Code 1 (Failed)

> Error Message:
> Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "LINKEDSERVERNAME". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7302)

Code 2 (Failed)

> Error Message:
> The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "LINKEDSERVERNAME221" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "LINKEDSERVERNAME221". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7399)

```
-- Code 1
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'LINKEDSERVERNAME',
 'Jet 4.0',
 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
 'F:\alpha_2\test.xls',
 NULL,
 'Excel 8.0'
GO
-- Code 2
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'LINKEDSERVERNAME221',
   'ACE 12.0',
   'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
   'F:\alpha_2\test.xls',
   NULL,
   'Excel 5.0';
GO
```

Comment: Where is the file located? Can SQL Server access this location?

Comment: Does the SQL Server service account have access/permissions to that file? (Assuming it is actually on the server. This won't work at all if it is located on the client machine)

Comment: Dear Alex, Yes file located on same PC and SQL Server can access the files on same location if it is .xlsx format I have issue with .xls files only

Comment: Dear Charlie, Yes file located on same server

Comment: Hello any hope please